# Split data into another worksheet vb6.0

Tags: excel, vb6

Right now I already create new Excel workbook. BUT, I want to split the data to new worksheet based on column.

Here, the output that will look like in Excel.
[image]

And, I want column Name for value 'Lucy' remain same worksheet and value 'Amir' will be in new worksheet.

Currently, I have this coding code that create new Excel. I don't have any idea how to start code for add new worksheet. Is it related with 'loop' or 'if-else then'

```vb
Dim Rsx As New ADODB.Recordset
        
Dim data2Rs As New ADODB.Recordset
sqlreport = qryline
Debug.Print sqlreport
Dim rsReport As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsReport = New ADODB.Recordset
   
Dim warehsecol As Integer, intRow As Integer, intCol As Integer, oricolidx As Integer

rsReport.Open sqlreport, wsDB
Debug.Print sqlreport

If rsReport.EOF Then 'no record
    xrecord = "N"

Else 'record exists
    xrecord = "Y"
    
    Dim excelApp As New excel.Application       
    Dim wbReport As Workbook
    Dim wsReport As Worksheet
    Dim rejRs As ADODB.Recordset

    excelApp.Visible = False
    excelApp.ScreenUpdating = False
    excelApp.Interactive = False
    excelApp.IgnoreRemoteRequests = True
    
    Set wbReport = excelApp.Workbooks.Add
    Set wsReport = wbReport.ActiveSheet
    
    '***Formatting
    With wsReport
        .Cells(2, 2).Value = "NAME"
        .Cells(2, 3).Value = "ORDER"
        .Cells(2, 4).Value = "PRICE"

        .Rows(4).Font.Bold = True
        .Rows(4).Font.Color = vbBlue

        Dim strCategory, strLossCat, strLossQty As String

        intRow = 6 'Starting row# for data insertion
    
        reccount = 0
        Do While Not rsReport.EOF
            reccount = reccount + 1
            reccount.Refresh

            .Cells(intRow, 2).Value = name
            .Cells(intRow, 3).Value = order
            .Cells(intRow, 4).Value = price

            intRow = intRow + 1
                
            rsReport.MoveNext
        Loop
             
        .Range("A1").Select
    End With
    wsReport.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
End If
'---------------------------
rsReport.Close
Set rsReport = Nothing

wsReport.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
wbReport.SaveAs "C:\report\" & "sale".xlsx"
wbReport.Close
```

Please help

Comment: Is this VBA code (an Excel macro)?  Or actually VB6?

Comment: This is VB6.0 . This is some part of my coding for create the excel.